# When I open my output file in cobol, random characters appear

Tags: cobol

here is the code i am running (it is not mine, it is from my professor but I can't seem to make it work. Help please.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. ACPTDSP1.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT GRDFILE ASSIGN TO DISK.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  GRDFILE        
       DATA RECORD IS GRDREC
    LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
       VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "C:\COBOL\GRDFILE.TXT".
   01  GRDREC.
         05 FILLER PIC X(80).
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *  INPUT DATA USING  *
  *  ACCEPT & DISPLAY  *
   01  NAME PIC X(25).
   01  MIDGRD   PIC 9V99.
   01  FINGRD   PIC 9V99.
   01  AVE      PIC 9V99.
   01  ANS      PIC X. 
  *  OUTPUT FILE  *
   01  HDG.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(32) VALUE SPACES.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(25) VALUE "STUDENT'S GRADE".
       05 FILLER    PIC X(33) VALUE SPACES.
   01  COLHDG.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(14) VALUE SPACES.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(12)  VALUE "STUDENT NAME".
       05 FILLER    PIC X(28) VALUE SPACES.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(12)  VALUE "FINAL GRADE ".
   01  GRDDATA.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(14) VALUE SPACES.
       05 NAME-OUT  PIC X(25).
       05 FILLER    PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
       05 AVE-OUT   PIC 9.99.
   SCREEN SECTION.
   01  CLRSCR.
       05 BLANK SCREEN.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-RTN.
       DISPLAY CLRSCR.
       OPEN OUTPUT GRDFILE.
       WRITE GRDREC FROM HDG.
       WRITE GRDREC FROM COLHDG.
       PERFORM PROCESS-RTN THRU PROCESS-END
            UNTIL ANS = 'N' OR ANS = 'n'.
       CLOSE GRDFILE.
       STOP RUN.
   PROCESS-RTN.
       DISPLAY (5, 15) "Enter Name: ".
       ACCEPT  (5, 30) NAME.
       DISPLAY (7, 15) "Enter Midterm Grade: ".
       ACCEPT  (7, 40) MIDGRD.
       DISPLAY (9, 15) "Enter Final Grade: ".
       ACCEPT  (9, 40) FINGRD.
       COMPUTE AVE = (MIDGRD + FINGRD) / 2.
       MOVE NAME TO NAME-OUT.
       MOVE AVE TO AVE-OUT.
       DISPLAY (11, 15) "Average Grade is:  ", AVE-OUT. 
       WRITE GRDREC FROM GRDDATA .
       DISPLAY (15, 15) "ENTER ANOTHER [Y/N]?   ".
       ACCEPT  ANS.
   PROCESS-END.
```

The problem I have is that when i open the grdfile, it shows random characters like cross and chinese characters.

if you have any idea, please do help. I want to learn. TIA

Comment: Maybe an encoding problem?

Comment: Name of compiler and OS. Also show an example of the output you are getting.

Comment: Some Cobol shops set their Cobol compiler to pre-initialize working storage.  Some do not.  It can be confusing to those that have not encountered this difference.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc but what would you suggest needs to be initialised? I can't see anything without a VALUE which isn't the target of something before it is written.

Comment: @Bill Woodger: The Cobol statement " WRITE GRDREC FROM GRDDATA" moves a 63 byte 01 record to an 80 byte 01 record.  I'm not sure if an 01 move to an 01 move pads the result.  If the OP named the  GRDREC 05 FILLER, and moved GRDDATA to the 05 field and did the WRITE, the blank padding might take place.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Well, I'm certain. It is in the Standard.

Comment: It should not be necessary, but you should be able to force data division init with "IS INITIAL PROGRAM".  Fillers won't get initialised from the procedure division.  Yes moves to larger items get padded unless reference modification is used.

Comment: @mckenzm This program will be started in the initial state, so `IS INITIAL` would be superflous, as you say "not necessary", so why mention it? All the `FILLER`s in the `WORKING-STORAGE` have `VALUE` clauses, so what would need to be initialised in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION` anyway? Unless reference-modification is used for the *target* field and only specifies *part* of the data. Not used in the program.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you just write the headers ? What happens if you hard code the ACCEPTed values ? A hexdump of the file would clarify a lot.

I've run this on a number of platforms and it behaves.

Strange characters will generally mean it is not 7 bit ASCII, UTF-8, or latin1 - and it should be 7 bit ASCII by default, so what are you using to view it ? Also consider compile options if character sets or EOL (end of line) or BOM (byte order) options are set ?

Comment: Hello Bill,  it is common to initialise group items in the procedure division (although moving a constant block is more efficient especially if MVC's are alignment optimised). It may jog the OP to mention it.
We need the OP to develop debugging skills after all.  So what are the contents of the fields and when do they change etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work perfectly well for me.

You should note that the size of `HDG` is 32+25+33=90, of `COLHDG` is 14+12+28+12=66 and `GRDDATA` is 14+25+20+4=63.

It may be that the compiler you are using is outputting random data on those short records as the output records are of length 80. I'd pad the short records out to 80 with filler pic x(14) value spaces and pic x(17) for the second and see whether that cures the problem.

Remember, the output will appear to be one giant string as far as a text editor is concerned...

Comment: The WRITE FROM is an implicit MOVE to the GRDREC. The long one will be truncated (losing some blanks) and the short ones will be padded with blanks, just like any MOVE.